# Can I use production org as a testing org?

Tags: deployment, sandbox, production

What are the pros and cons of using production org as a testing org?

Comment: You mean, testing code in your actual production org at the same time as users are using the org? Or are you talking about licencing a production org just to test in?

Comment: Renu, what do you consider "testing" ? Without a more detailed scope or context for which you'd like to see information this question is very broad and vague. That makes it quite hard to answer anything that is not way too general. You can still edit the question to provide more insight into your full question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes You can but it is not recommended! 
In sales force development plus testing environment is you sandbox. You complete your development then for testing feed the values in the respective forms (Lead, Account..) and then test your functionality on the sandbox itself. once you OK with your test then move the entire customization to your production.Your sandbox data is not copied to production.